# How to open the filedialog after pressing the button?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library, openfiledialog

I would like to open the filedialog after pressing a button. Then I could choose an image and display it on a canvas. (My goal is to do a very simple image editor) Unfortunately, the filedialog open up automatically when I start the program. Is there a way for example to do something like this:

- press a button to open the filedialog
- choose an image
- display the image on the canvas

Here is my code that I've done so far

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()   
#function to select my image by using the filedialog
def select_image(): 
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return Image.open(file_path)

#button to press to open filedialog
select = Button(root, text="select an image", command=select_image)
select.pack()

#the canvas where the image will be display
canvas = Canvas(root, width= 400, height=400, bg="grey")
canvas.pack()

image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(select_image())
canvas.create_image(200,200, image= image_tk)   
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to refactor your code as you are calling select_image() inside PhotoImage and it will automatically open the dialog. You can use a variable to store once the filedialog returns the image,

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very experienced with programming in python yet ! I'm not sure to understand what do you mean by 'I need to refactor my code' ?

Comment: When I store in a variable the image choosen in the filedialog, and then I use the variable in my code, it says that my variable is not defined .I think it is because I haven't chosen my image yet

Comment: If it is possible I would like to choose an image with the filedialog and then use my image to do some modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filedialog opens because of this line:

image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(select_image())

My Solution is:

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, Frame, Button, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Gui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.select = Button(self.master, text="select an image", command=self.select_image)
        self.select.pack()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.master, width= 400, height=400, bg="grey")
        self.canvas.pack()

    def select_image(self): 
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        des = Image.open(file_path)
        bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(des)
        self.canvas.bg_image = bg_image
        self.canvas.create_image(200,200, image=self.canvas.bg_image)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = Gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Woaw, it works perfectly ! That exactly what I was looking for. Thank you